# Another way to prove that all its members of a sequence are positive integers without using matrix.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let's be sequence $ (u_n) $  is defined by $u_1=1$, $u_{n+1} =2 u_n+\sqrt{3 u_n^2+6}, \quad \forall n \geq 1.$ Prove that all its members are positive integers.

I tried by using matrix. 
    Put  $ v_n = \sqrt{3 u_n^2+6} $, then $ v_n^2 - 3u_n^2 = 6 $ and
    $$ u_{n+1}=2u_n + v_n, \quad \forall n \geq 1. $$
    We have
\begin{align*}
v_{n+1}^2 &= 3u_{n+1}^2 + 6\\
&= 3(2u_n + v_n)^2 +v_n^2 - 3u_n^2\\
&= 9u_n^2 + 12 u_n v_n + 4v_n^2\\
&= (3u_n + 2 v_n)^2\\
\end{align*}
Then, $ v_{n+1} = 3u_n + 2 v_n. $
We have
$$ \left( \begin{array}{c}
u_1  \\
v_1 \\
\end{array}\right)  = \left( \begin{array}{c}
1  \\
3 \\
\end{array}\right), \quad \left( \begin{array}{c}
u_{n+1}  \\
v_{n+1} \\
\end{array}\right)  = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
2& 1  \\
3 &2 \\
\end{array}\right)\left( \begin{array}{c}
u_n  \\
v_n \\
\end{array}\right)$$

Thus all the numbers $u_ n$ and $v_ n , n ≥ 2,$ are positive integers.

How can I solve this prolbem without using matrix?

Comment: The recursion in that Q&A is slightly different, but the identical techniques work in your case and show that $u_{n+1} = 4 u_n - u_{n-1}$.

Comment: In addition, you don't have to write it using a matrix. You already have the recurrence relation (over 2 variables), so checking that the base cases are integers is sufficient.